# How is getZipList defined?

Tags: haskell, applicative

I am curious about where getZipList is defined in ghc.
Control.Applicative has this definition for ZipList.

```
newtype ZipList a = ZipList { getZipList :: [a] }
```

One way to use ZipLists is (from LYAH):

```
ghci> getZipList $ (+) <$> ZipList [1,2,3] <*> ZipList [100,100,100]

[101,102,103]
```

I am curious how getZipList knows what to return.
Perhaps I am missing something about the newtype keyword.
Thanks!

Answer (score 12, accepted):

It's not just `newtype`, it works the same with `data`. What you seem to be unaware of is named field syntax,

```
newtype ZipList a = ZipList { getZipList :: [a] }
```

is almost the same as

```
newtype ZipList a = ZipList [a]

getZipList :: ZipList a -> [a]
getZipList (ZipList xs) = xs
```

but the named field syntax allows more convenient updating and pattern matching - in particular it's much more convenient for named fields in `data` types with multiple fields.

The named field (implicitly) defines the accessor function that extracts the contained data from the wrapped value.

Comment: Yes now I recall seeing the record syntax. Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

The secret is not in the newtype definition but in the applicative instance it has for <*>

```
instance Applicative ZipList where  
pure x = ZipList (repeat x)  
ZipList fs <*> ZipList xs = ZipList [f x | (f,x) <- zip fs xs]
```

The default list is like this instead, and that is where the difference comes from

```
instance Applicative [] where  
pure x = [x]  
fs <*> xs = [f x | f <- fs, x <- xs]
```